# Traveling to Ireland with German National visa

Tags: visas, europe, germany, ireland, armenian-citizens

I am a student at the University of Stuttgart, Germany and I have a 1 year national visa for Germany and now as my holidays are ahead I was looking if my German visa is sufficient to travel to Ireland for some 10 days.
I am a citizen of Republic of Armenia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary: Your German visa is not enough, you need an Irish short-stay visa.**

Ireland is not part of the Schengen area, so a German national visa is not enough to enter the country. Since Armenia is on the list of “[countries whose nationals are visa required](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Countries%20whose%20nationals%20are%20visa%20required)”, you do generally need an Irish visa to go to Ireland on holidays.

There is however [an exemption for holders of student visas from other EU/EEA countries](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Check%20if%20you%20need%20a%20Visa), which could cover you. But that's only when going to Ireland “as part of a group school excursion” so it probably does not apply to the trip you are currently planning.